# Clojure deployment?

Tags: clojure

What is the easiest way to make a clojure app into an executable like http://rawr.rubyforge.org/ does for ruby? (exe and app files too)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [leiningen](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) and build an uberjar(standalone jar that contains all dependencies) from the project.

As Alex Ott mentions in the comment to my answer, another may to build your app is to use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) + Clojure plugin for maven. Afterward you may use a tool such as IzPack to generate an installer or an executable wrapper for your jar artifact. You may use [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) with leiningen as well of course - it doesn't care about the build system at all - only about the resulting files :-)

After you have the uberjar there are many option to wrap it in a native executable launcher for windows - [izpack2exe](http://izpack.org/documentation/izpack-utils.html#windows-executable-wrapper-izpack2exe), [jsmooth, jar2exe, executor, etc](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/convert-jar-to-exe-executable-jar-file-to-exe-converting/)...

Comment: I use maven with assembly plugin to build big jar with all content. And I also use maven + izpack-plugin to build installers for my applications

Comment: I use IzPack myself, but forgot to mention it. Thanks for the great comment, I'll extend my answer.

Comment: Clojuresque (the Clojure plugin for gradle) also provides an uberjar task, which builds a standalone jar for an application.

Comment: I don't want an installer. I just want to convert the jar to an app and exe.

Comment: lein uberjar, couldn't be more simple, best option IMHO

Comment: There is too much Maven and Gradle noise here when this is a Clojure ecosystem question -- please see if Leiningen meets your needs before marching backwards in time.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Bozhidar's answer leiningen makes it super easy to generate a jar that packages your app and its dependencies. Just run lein uberjar from the terminal when you are inside your project directory and it will create a file project-name-0.1.0-standalone.jar that can be run with java -jar where "project-name" is the name of your project. You want to make sure that is your project.clj you set :main to your file that has a -main function. Also in your main file you want to put (:gen-class) inside your namespace declaration like so:

```
    (ns project-name.main
      (: require ...)
      (:gen-class))
```